# Expression showing as a json format. firebase

Tags: angularjs, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I'm trying to show the data from my database using ng-repeat. However when I try to retrieve the equipment data under system. It shows it as a json format. How do i retrieve the other nodes under equipments? Need help.

**My Angular**

```
    /*global angular*/
var app = angular.module('input', ['ngRoute', 'firebase']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    'use strict';
    $routeProvider.when('/input', {
        templateUrl: 'input/input.html',
        controller: 'inputCtrl'
    });
}]);

app.controller('inputCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebaseObject', '$firebaseArray', function ($scope, $firebaseObject, $firebaseArray) {
    'use strict';

    $scope.message;
    $scope.writeUserData = function (equipment, system) {
        firebase.database().ref('data/' + $scope.system + '/equipments').child(equipment).set({
        equipment: equipment
});
        $scope.message = "Added"
};


        var ref = firebase.database().ref();
    var data = ref.child("data");
    var list = $firebaseArray(data);

    list.$loaded().then(function(data) {
        $scope.data = data;
        console.log($scope.data);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        $scope.error = error;
    });

}]);
```

**My Html**

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="data in data">
                  <td class="select" align="center">

                    <div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-3" tabindex="1">
                    <span>{{data.$id}}</span>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="#">{{data.equipments}}</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>

                    </td>
                </tr>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to list each equipment as a list item? If so, you could try using `ng-repeat`.

Comment: I did use ng-repeat!

Comment: I was looking for it in the `<li>` tag - honest mistake. Though I have never used `data-ng-repeat` before, so on that note (unfortunately) I cannot help you.

Answer (score 1):

have your tryed to change

```
data in data
```

to some thing like

```
d in data
```

also to iterate equipments you will need one more ng-repeat

```
 <li ng-repeat= "equipment in d.equipments"><a href="#">{{data.equipments}}</a></li>
```

havent tested the code!

Comment: Alright so i tested out your code, but it is still giving me a json array under the dropdown!

Answer (score 1):

Alright I found a solution to my problem.

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="d in data">
                  <td class="select" align="center">

                    <div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-3" tabindex="1">
                    <span>{{d.$id}}</span>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li data-ng-repeat="equipment in d.equipments"><a>{{equipment.equipment}}</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>

                    </td>
                </tr>
```